# ¿Cómo aplicar transparencia a polígono en Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Dibujo un polígono y quería aplicar al relleno del polígono un transparencia. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
PolygonOptions PG = new PolygonOptions();
PG.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
```

Esto hace que el polígono esté con relleno de color celeste. Lo que necesito es tener el color celeste con una transparencia. ¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?

Este es el código completo de mi aplicación:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("SAICoffeeSQL", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
Cursor cr = db.rawQuery("select Latitud, Longitud from TB_previos_productor", null);
PolygonOptions PG = new PolygonOptions();
while(cr.moveToNext()) {
    PG.add(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Latitud"))).doubleValue(),
        Double.valueOf(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Longitud"))).doubleValue()));
}
cr.close();
db.close();
//aquí tengo el problema
PG.fillColor(Color.CYAN).strokeColor(Color.BLUE).strokeWidth(1);

Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(PG);SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("SAICoffeeSQL", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
Cursor cr = db.rawQuery("select Latitud, Longitud from TB_previos_productor", null);
PolygonOptions PG = new PolygonOptions();
while(cr.moveToNext()){
    PG.add(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Latitud"))).doubleValue(),
                    Double.valueOf(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Longitud"))).doubleValue()));
}
cr.close();
db.close();
PG.fillColor(Color.CYAN).strokeColor(Color.BLUE).strokeWidth(1);
Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(PG);
```

Comment: Esto parece más bien una tarea

Comment: Porfavor, agrega una descripción útil de tu problema y un resumen de lo que has hecho hasta ahora para solucionarlo

Comment: en el poligono que se dibuja,  el relleno sea una transparencia, :FILLCOLOR(Color.BLUE) <----- que sea color transparencia

Comment: ok gracias por su tiempo es Fillcolor(Color.argb(aa, rr, gg, bb)

Comment: Hola @MarkHernandez. La pregunta no es clara. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar más detalles sobre el problema que tienes con ese código.

Comment: Hola @Mark. He actualizado tu pregunta y respuesta para mostrarte un ejemplo de cómo deberían lucir para ser útiles para ti y visitantes futuros al sitio. Espero que sigas publicando preguntas y/o respuestas en el sitio :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He resuelto el problema al utilizar un método de `Color` que me permite agregar la transparencia mediante el método [`Color#argb`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), donde el primer argumento `aa` es el que me permite indicar la transparencia.

El código quedaría así:

```
  PG.fillColor(Color.argb(128, 0, 255, 255));
```

Comment: Hola @Mark. Por favor brinda una explicación del código, no se entiende qué es lo que se resuelve con esto.

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas la documentación [PolygonOptions fillColor (int color)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolygonOptions.html#public-methods)

> **fillColor** : Especifica el color de relleno del polígono, como ARGB de
>   32 bits. El color predeterminado es el negro (0xFF000000).

Por lo tanto, suponiendo que quieres un color [CYAN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#CYAN), usarias `0xFF00FFFF`. Si deseas aplicar una transparencia (primeros bits) media (50%) sería `0x8000FFFF`,

```
PG.fillColor(0x8000FFFF);
```

Usando valores decimales se puede realizar mediante [Color.argb()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), por lo tanto [convirtiendo](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) el valor `80` hexadecimal es 128 en decimal y `FF` es 255, usando valores decimales tendríamos:

```
PG.fillColor(Color.argb(128, 0, 255, 255));
```